# In the first Matrix film, would Neo have died if Cypher had unplugged him like the other crew members?

Tags: the-matrix

We already know that the One cannot die in the Matrix so he can fulfill his purpose (source: M1 ending and M2), meaning the Matrix doesn't "delete" his mind as with a normal red/blue pill. Also more tentatively, from the third movie we know that the One has the ability to materialize his mind in the Matrix without a wired connection (which is presumably how he is able to "hack" Sentinels and also to see machines while blind) although this probably requires interaction with the Source.

Comment: Source on your claims? M1 certainly doesn't state anything of the sort.

Comment: @OrangeDog The immortality part is demonstrated, in M1 at least. Because the prophecy is shown to be another form of control in M2 we can assume the One needs to be kept alive to eventually reboot the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

In the first movie, when Cypher was unplugging crew members, Neo wasn't The One. So he would die like the rest of them. It is also unclear if abrupt unplugging of The One kills him or not, we haven't seen such situation.

Comment: Can you offer any evidence to back this up?

Comment: I do not think there is any evidence, the same way there is any evidence to support the hidden assumption of the question (that Neo should be treated preferably by the Matrix, even though he is not even The One). On my part this is a kind of Occam's razor thinking: at that moment he was just a regular crew member, there is not reason to suspect that he should receive special treatment. We do not know when Matrix decides who gets The One package assigned (and with it perhaps some preferential treatment).

Comment: @Anxhr The privileges of The One seem to be a sort of "cheat mode" for the Matrix, allowing him to bend the rules of the simulation to a greater degree than even the red pills (dodging/stopping bullets, flight, defeating Agents in melee, immortality). As for your theory that Neo wasn't the One until a certain point, it is invalidated by Trinity's prophecy from the Oracle.

Comment: Ok, but even if it was decided beforehand that Neo would become The One, it does not mean he was The One during Cypher's spree (or that he would receive some sort of 'immortality' protection from the Matrix). Perhaps Matrix does not care that much about individuals and in case of Neo's death it would select a different person to become The One (and Trinity would eventually fall in love with this new person). Who knows what Oracle "saw". These feel like conjectures on our part, I think these details are kept vague on purpose.

Comment: Evidence that he’s not yet The One is his conversation with The Oracle. She confirms he’s not The One, at least during their conversation. She says he’s got it in him but it seems like he’s waiting for something. Another reason to believe that he doesn’t start off as the one but changes into the one is how the matrix looks different to him after his rebirth - he can see the code (or whatever that is meant to be). Isn’t there a whole thing about potential “The Ones” in later movies or am I getting that mixed up with the Buffyverse?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely he would have died. There's two things from the movie that point to this

1. Neo is clearly not The One at this point in the movie (he won't even start to believe for some time yet). Without any sort of powers, he would have been helpless to stay alive upon disconnection
2. Even after Neo becomes The One, we see him race to the phone to exit The Matrix before the EMP goes off. This implies he would have died had he not exited properly.

Comment: Neo didn't know the ship was under attack by sentinels. He was just trying to get out

Comment: My point is that Neo couldn't just *will* himself out. He still had to use the phone.